# Selective code functionality

Tags: assembly, x86

```
err:    
MOV AH, 0x0E
MOV BX, 0x0007
MOV SI, 6
.loop:
MOV AL, [SI+.msg-1]
INT 0x10
DEC SI
JNZ .loop
JMP restart    ;jumps to the start of the program to for all intents and purposes equivalent to a complete reset
.msg db CR, LF, ".rrE"
```

This code is part of a larger program and prints the message "Err." (of course excluding the quotation marks) followed by a linefeed and carriage return. This works on my laptop with a *Intel Atom N570 64bit Dual core*, but not on my PC with a *Intel Core i5-3570K 64bit Quad core* nor my laptop with a *AMD turion 64 X2 64bit Dual core*. On the latter two a series of six blanks are printed instead.

This code can only be reached via a `JMP err` command and the entire program works, as far as I was able to test, equivalent on all three CPU's.

I wrecked my brain on this for a while now, because I was sure it was some stupendously simple thing I had overlooked. Since this was of no avail, here is my cry for help towards the internet... What could be the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Your `CR` and `LF` seem reversed. A normal EOL on the console is `CRLF`; you're printing it out as `LFCR`. This shouldn't normally matter, but try it in the reverse order and see what happens.

Comment: That is an artefact from when I used a, I think, corrupt USB drive to boot the program from. It only worked with LFCR and printed an array of random looking symbols otherwise, plus it had some other weird and unexplained peculiarities. Anyhow, I tried your suggestion, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Is `ds` pointed to your data?

Comment: So it was a stupendously simple thing after all. Thank you, that did the trick. I changed it to `MOV AL, [CS:SI+.msg-1]` and it worked. I feel really stupid now. =S

Comment: Nobody is born knowing this stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Your segment setup is incorrect. In real mode, you should usually start your program with

```
mov ax,cs
mov ds,ax
; ...

or

mov ax,data_segment
mov ds,ax
```

If you forget this little step, the code will seem right, but memory read/writes based on `DS` will end up at wrong addresses. Your blanks are probably `NULL` bytes from somewhere.

On the Atom, your `CS` and `DS` "coincidentally" match.